# EclipseLink Drop-and-create tables options

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I'm having a problem with eclipse link and its drop-and-create-tables attribute. I am using JPA to persist/commit data to a MySQL database, so on first doing this, the tables are generated and the data is written to the database. Now I want to query the database using JPQL, to create the query I need to use an entity manager and when I do this the tables are dropped and created again.

Just wondering is there a way around this?

Comment: You probably recreate the EntityManagerFactory, which you shouldn't do. The EMF should be created once, and then be shared and reused each time you need an EntityManager.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks for that, that is what I am doing, I create an entity manager factory in one class, then I need to use it in another class so I create it again, whats the best way to avoid this?, sorry but total newbie to this. thanks again

Comment: Create it once and store it in some singleton, so that you can access it later.